# How can I allow someone to access my VM?

Tags: 14.04, users

I just added a user in linux, and give a password.

```
   useradd dluiz
   passwd dluiz
```

---

Now, I tried ssh into my vm as that user I got

```
ssh dluiz@ip
```

I got

`Permission denied (publickey).`

---

Try again with the `-v`

ssh dluiz@ip

I got

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 104.236.15.216 [104.236.15.216] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/dluiz/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/dluiz/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/dluiz/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/dluiz/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/dluiz/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/dluiz/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/dluiz/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/dluiz/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 104.236.15.216:22 as 'ckoll'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:I+hXqTRQsphODSjENJw3338uJAjVc5CE34LTeA99A
debug1: Host '104.236.15.216' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/dluiz/.ssh/known_hosts:42
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/dluiz/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dluiz/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dluiz/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dluiz/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

---

what do I need in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to proceed the log-in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read all about how to configure sshd_config by typing `man sshd_config`.

The particular option you want is `PasswordAuthentication yes`.

Comment: I have that set to `yes` already. Maybe I just need to `service ssh restart`

Comment: I'm in now, after restarting my ssh. Thanks for pointing out the option.